# How to test buffer in webflux

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I want to write a unit test for my below gist

```
private Flux<String> replayWithData(final Replay replay, final Checkpoint checkpoint) {
         return service.findAll(replay.getData())
                  .buffer()
                  .flatMap(id -> processAndReplay(id, replay,checkpoint));
}

private Flux<String> processAndReplay(List<String> ids, Replay replay, Checkpoint){
         return Flux.fromIterable(ids). //so on process
}
```

now I am writing unit test like this

```
@Test
public void replaySuccessTest(){
     when(service.findAll(any())).thenReturn(Flux.just("data1", "data2"));

     Flux<String> result = replayService.replayWithData(replayJob, null);
}
```

but my test case is stuck `buffer()` method, it is not going ahead.

Answer (score 0):

In reactive nothing happened until you subscribe. Typically, framework like WebFlux would subscribe to it for you.

As for tests, the best way to test reactive flows is to use `StepVerifier` that subscribes to the flow and provides fluent API for testing reactive flows.

Here is simplified version of you flow

```
private Flux<String> replayWithData() {
    return service.findAll()
            .buffer()
            .flatMap(ids -> processAndReplay(ids));
}
private Flux<String> processAndReplay(List<String> ids) {
    return Flux.fromIterable(ids)
            .map(id -> "#" + id);
}
```

and test for it

```
@Test
void testReplayWithData() {
    when(service.findAll())
            .thenReturn(Flux.just("data1", "data2"));

    StepVerifier.create(replayWithData())
            .expectNext("#data1", "#data2")
            .verifyComplete();
}
```